# Dart packages problems with intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, package

I'm actually trying to use Dart in IntelliJ IDEA, and I have successfully install the plugin for it, but I face numerous others problems.
But the problem I want to resolve the most, is the fact that for some packages, IntelliJ doesn't show the sources inside it and not with particular reason...
The whole project work in Dart Editor, and launch correctly, so the problem is not from pubspec.yaml.

To makes me more understandable, I will say that I "pub get" correctly the packages A and B, so they appear as folder link in IntelliJ :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOUKD.jpg

But like you see, I cannot enter in the b package to see the files inside it. I have checked the structure of the two folders without noticing any difference.

The more ridiculous in that is, I can see some of the files inside the B package in the editor of IntelliJ via Ctrl+Click in the dart files that import the files inside the B package. And it doesn't work for all of them ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'b' is a 'path package' in your project. That means that b original source code is located on your computer and you specified path to it in pubspec.yaml. IntelliJ IDEA excludes all copies and leaves only original files in project. Root 'packages' folder is not excluded, but all its copies (for example in web folder) are excluded. packages/b is a copy and it is excluded. To work normally with source files from b package you should add path to b as a separate content root: Project Structure | Modules | your Dart module | Add content root.

In IntelliJ IDEA 14 excluded folders are visible by default. Use cases when you need to see excluded folder contents are rare so you may safely hide them (the option is under the gear in the Project View tool window title). With it you will see empty node in packages/b with a hint that it is just a link to b/lib folder. And anyway you should have path to b configured as a content root.

Comment: Thanks for your quite clear answer. I was expecting that IntelliJ was doing this for a good reason, and it was, because it's true that in the majority of the cases, you do not need to see the source of the packages you import. But for my precise case I needed to see the source of this package. So I was a bit disarmed by my non knowledge of the machinery of IntelliJ.

Comment: Anyway, now that I have downloaded and installed the early access version, I am going to keep it until the official release is out.

Answer (score 0):

You should not open files of projects currently open in IntelliJ from the package folder but instead directly from the project. The `b/lib` after the folder icon indicates that this package is part of your currently opened IntelliJ project (may added as a `Resource Root`)

When you navigate to a referenced file <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> the file is not opened from the packages symlink but from the package in your IntelliJ project (as you should do it manually as well).

Comment: Actually I have found a way to reach some files, I use the path bar in the top, but I have to find a file that display the full path, and not the project path. But I still doesn't understand where I can find these files in the navigation window.

Comment: `B` should be available in the `Project` view (`View` > `Tool Window` > `Project`) as node just below the top level node.

Comment: This is not what I expected. What is the name of the package (name value in `pubspec.yaml` file?

Comment: Oh I found something interesting, It seems that all the packages that I cannot access are all the packages I import in the different pubspec.yaml with a specified path (I use only relative, so I don't know if non-relative work). And all the packages I can navigate through are the ones with the keyword "any". I have not completely verified my affirmation, but at the first examination it seems to be this.

Comment: And I add that in Dart Editor it works perfectly well. I can access these files with this manipulation. I just prefer IntelliJ so I have to try.

Comment: That seems right. You should add those packages to your IntelliJ project. `File` > `Settings` > `Project: projectname` > `Directories` > `+ Add Content Root` (might differ for you - I use WebStorm).

Comment: IntelliJ handles packages/projects differently. I discovered this very recently (through support from JetBrains). If you have configured your project correctly it is way superior than in DartEditor. I forgot - in the directories you should exclude the packages directories from sub-directories like `bin`, `web`, `test` for the additional content root directories.

Comment: I don't find it for the moment, I will try tomorrow. But thanks for your time :)

Comment: It might look differently. I use WebStorm 9 beta and here the organization of the settings items changed notably after some update a few weeks ago.

Comment: I have updated to the early access release and it works. Thanks for bringing me to install the beta update :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to update IntelliJ to the Early Access update (139.2).
So this question will be useless in the next update, I will delete her at that moment.